# Рандом с условиями

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Мне нужно присвоить 8 переменным типа int присвоить рандомные значения от 1 до 4, но чтобы каждое значение встречалось 2 раза обязательно.

Comment: с каким распределением?

Comment: Заполнить 4 переменных **разными** значениями, а потом добавить их же в оставшиеся 4?

Answer (score 3):

Пожалуй, самым логичным будет сделать массив с 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, и 8 раз выбирать с помощью rand одно из оставшихся

```
int(__int64(rand()) * Nost / RAND_MAX)
```

и помечать выбывшие

Answer (score 2):

Взять массив {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4} и от него -- перестановку со случайным номером.